# Read old messages on iotHub cloud-to-device queue

Tags: c#, node.js, azure-iot-hub

I have a node.js code (the device side) that listens to messages on a device queue of azure IotHub.

In the next scenario:

1. code is not running
2. a message been sent to the device.
3. code is starting to run and listen to the queue.

The device is not reading the old message from the queue, just if I send new message - it will read it.

How can I change the device code to listen to old messages as well?

Comment: That’s not the expected behavior. The device should receive all messages in its queue when it connects. An interesting way of seeing if it’s an SDK bug would be to set the DEBUG env variable to “*” and look at the logs to determine if the message is sent by the service and swallowed by the SDK or if it isn’t even sent by the service.  Finally as a good SO practice please consider posting your code and logs in the question after scrubbing for secrets.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this article to understand [Azure IoT Hub Cloud-to-device Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d). From the diagram which shows the lifecycle state graph for a cloud-to-device message in IoT Hub, IoT Hub persists cloud-to-device messages in per-device queues. Devices must explicitly acknowledge completion for IoT Hub to remove them from the queue. This approach guarantees resiliency against connectivity and device failures.

In the document which introduces how to [send cloud-to-device messages with IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-c2d)  for node.js, if run the SendCloudToDeviceMessage.js at first, the message will be enqueued, and then when running SimulatedDevice.js(plese note the modification of the **connectCallback** function to handle messages with **Complete** method), the client will receive the messages.

```
var connectCallback = function (err) {
if (err) {
  console.log('Could not connect: ' + err);
} else {
  console.log('Client connected');
  client.on('message', function (msg) {
      console.log('Id: ' + msg.messageId + ' Body: ' + msg.data);
      client.complete(msg, printResultFor('completed'));
    });
  }
};
```